# TagBox Column and comments

Tags: front-end, boxes, input-forms, column

This provides a useful input format, extendable with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
CellPrint[Cell[
  BoxData[RowBox[{"(", "\[NoBreak]", 
     TagBox[GridBox[{{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"4"}, {"5"}}], Column], "\[NoBreak]", 
     ")"}]], "Input"]]
```

> [image]

The generated cell evaluates to a flat `List`:

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

However adding a comment produces a spurious `Null`:

[image]

> ```
> {1, 2 Null, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

Without the `TagBox[. . ., Column]` comments work normally, but input is not recognized as a flat list:

```
CellPrint[Cell[
  BoxData[RowBox[{"(", "\[NoBreak]", GridBox[{{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"4"}, {"5"}}], 
     "\[NoBreak]", ")"}]], "Input"]]
```

[image]

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
> ```

Is there a similar flat-list input construction that allows comments?

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for tagging; I'm out of practice.

Comment: Some testing shows that no matter where you put the `TagBox` it breaks when you add a comment, because the FE interprets `RowBox[{"a", RowBox[{"(*", "b", "*)}]}]` incorrectly. On the other hand `TemplateBox` has a flexible `InterpretationFunction` option that you could use to take a `GridBox` input and handle it correctly, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fragile hack

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[
  BoxData[
   TemplateBox[
    {
     GridBox[{{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"4"}, {"5"}}]
     },
    "InputListColumn",
    DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{"(", #, ")"} &),
    InterpretationFunction -> (
      DeleteCases[
        RowBox[Prepend["{"]@Append["}"]@Riffle[Flatten@#[[1]], ","]],
        RowBox[{"(*", ___, "*)"}], 
        Infinity
        ] &
      )
    ]
   ],
  "Input"
  ]
```

But it works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! btw https://youtu.be/QWGjjw0ZwXk?t=130

Comment: This appears more resilient: `InterpretationFunction -> (DeleteCases[#, RowBox[{"(*", ___, "*)"}], Infinity] /. gb_GridBox :> TagBox[gb, Column] &)`